# Android changing locale - buttons not working anymore

Tags: android, button, locale, onclicklistener

I am coding an android application and I am trying allow user to select a language manually within application. I put languages that application supports in options menu.

I don't have problems with translating the app, that is working just fine. My problem is, that when I change the language of the application (translate) other buttons that I have in my application stop working (like there is no onClickListener). And also my onNewIntent() (that I overrode) method is not working anymore. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code of translating the app:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.lan_EN) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "English", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

        Locale mLocale = new Locale("");
        Locale.setDefault(mLocale); 
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration(); 
        if (!config.locale.equals(mLocale)) 
        { 
            config.locale = mLocale; 
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null); 

            this.setContentView(R.layout.read_temp);
        }

        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.lan_ES) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Spanish", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

        Locale mLocale = new Locale("es");
        Locale.setDefault(mLocale); 
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration(); 
        if (!config.locale.equals(mLocale)) 
        { 
            config.locale = mLocale; 
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null); 

            this.setContentView(R.layout.read_temp);
        }

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Activity in Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ReadActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/tech_filter" />

    </activity>
```

Comment: you know... also any references to the views which you get in onCreate will not works ... guess why ... could you share how Activity is defined in manifest(are you messing with default configuration change handling? ) and how(and more important - where) you set onClickListeners?

Comment: only onClickListeners that are set in onCreate method are not working. And also the views as you said. How do I get around that?

Comment: the problem is ... setContentView ... it creates(and set) new view(and the old button is on ...well, old view) ... now add 2 and 2 :)

Comment: Ok, so how do I make changes that translation makes visible? If I dont add setContentView, the translation does not occur.

Comment: heh...just do the same thingy as you do in onCreate after setContentView ... findViewById, etc. (better: move it to some method and just call it to not copy&paste the same code)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am solving this. In my

```
InitializeIDsMethod();
```

What I am doing is , initializing all the buttons and their IDs and calling it on language chnage. I am calling the same method in onCreate() to void code redundancy.

```
 public void setlanguage(Context context, String ar) {


    Locale locale = new Locale(ar);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    InitializeIDsMethod();


}
```